# Qt 4: How to set outer border for QWidget so that its inner widgets are unaffected?

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I have quite a strange problem. I have a `QWidget` with `QHBoxLayout` on it. The layout contains two `QLabels`.
I want to set a border for this whole widget. I'm using style sheet:

```
 "padding: 10px;"
 "border-style: solid;"
 "border-width: 3px;"
 "border-radius: 7px;"
```

But here's the problem: this style is applied to both QLabels and completely breaks the layout. I only need the outer window to have the border, not the labels. 
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
.QWidget
{
    // your css rules
}
```

.QWidget will apply CSS only to classes that are EXACTLY QWidget and not inheriting QWidget

You can also use object name selector

```
#YourWidgetObjectName
{
    // your css rules
}
```

Both solutions wont apply rules to other widgets (even those inside)

Comment: I believe it should be QWidget, without the dot.

Comment: QWidget without the dot will indicate ale widgets that inherit QWidget. with dot it includes only instances of class QWidget itself. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types

Answer (score 6):

Style sheets will work recursively. If you apply style sheet to a Application it will be applied to all widgets within it. So you may have to specify to what you want to apply style sheet?

logic should be something like this..

```
QHBoxLayout#layoutbox {
     background-color: red;
     border-style: outset;
     border-width: 2px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     border-color: beige;
     font: bold 14px;
     min-width: 10em;
     padding: 6px;
 }
```

Comment: how can I set the stylesheet? In Qt4.8 the QHBoxLayout class has no function called `setStyleSheet()`. Should I do it in a different way, or does your answer only apply for Qt5 ?

Comment: A layout is not a widget. You cannot apply a stylesheet to a layout.